# Counting syscalls of a program and checking validity of the results with strace

Tags: c, linux, system-calls, strace, ptrace

I am using ptrace to count the syscalls of a program.
The problem is that given a program A, my program prints out the number of the syscalls made (open, close, read, write).

The results of my program and strace (with -c option) with program A as an argument, were identical, except for the open syscalls.
My program printed 15 and strace prints 3.

But I am guessing that as strace prints some other syscalls as well, these might sum up to the 15 open syscalls my program counted.

I am using SYS_open to check the results of ptrace when looking the ORIG_EAX/RAX register.

The syscalls that strace prints are [here.](http://pastebin.com/AyEx1bin)

**Update:**
I compiled my program from the terminal and ran it from there, and the results were the same with strace.
I am developing in netbeans.

Why did this happen?

Comment: @user315052: What is difference? I am just using `SYS_open`. (I've added an update half an hour ago, please take a look)

Comment: How do you calculate that you had 15 opens?  How many closes did you think you had?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: With a counter, each time the return from ptrace was SYS_open, I incremented it. Also, I avoided counting the syscalls two times (since wait returns twice (2 interrupts)). I had 3 closes (same as strace).

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like netbeans is using ptrace to control things. (After all, how can it do breakpoints and steps without it?) So netbeans may sending harmless signals to your program.

You can run strace -o /tmp/foo (without -c) to find out exactly what's going on. (compare the output under netbeans and without netbeans to see what's different.)

You can also add "-e open,close" if you want to filter to specific calls.

Comment: Hmm, might be this. When to run the strace command you've posted? One with the program I'm developing and another one with netbeans? (this doesn't sound right :P)